# Spring Data JDBC with MyBatis not finding custom query

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to use Spring Data JDBC with MyBatis.  I'm interested in using the out-of-the-box CRUD methods that CrudRepository provides and in writing ADDITIONAL custom queries defined in MyBatis XML files.

From reading the instructions from [jdbc.mybatis](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.mybatis) it sounds like all I need to do is create a `Mapper` that implements the method I'd like (adhering the the rule "*The name of the statement is constructed by concatenating the fully qualified name of the entity type with Mapper*") and add a method signature to my `CrudRepository`.  I've done that but Spring Data never seems to find my method and gives this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooApplication': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No query specified on findByChangeOwnerId; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on findByChangeOwnerId
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.fooApplication.main(fooApplication.java:42) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No query specified on findByChangeOwnerId; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on findByChangeOwnerId
```

I've also followed the example from [mybatis-spring-boot-sample](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/tree/master/mybatis-spring-boot-samples) but there's not a lot for me to go on with what's in there.

Questions are:

1. Can I add additonal methods to the CrudRepository that will call out to MyBatis?  If so can explain what I'm missing below?
2. I assume for any additonal methods I can pass in whatever arguments I want as opposed to always having to pass in the `MyBatisContext`?

My CrudRepository

```
package com.xxx.repository.jdbc;

import com.xxx.model.Foo;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface FooBmtRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, String> {  
  List<Foo> findByChangeOwnerId(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

src/main/resources/application.yml

```
mybatis:
  mapper-locations: classpath:/mapper/**/*.xml
  configuration:
    map-underscore-to-camel-case: true
```

Mapper XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.xxx.model.ItsmMapper">
    <!--<select id="findByChangeOwnerId" resultType="com.xxx.model.Itsm" parameterType="org.springframework.data.jdbc.mybatis.MyBatisContext">-->
    <!--where change_owner_id=#{changeOwnerId}-->
    <select id="findByChangeOwnerId" resultMap="itsmResultMap" parameterType="String">
        select *
        from [myschema].[tbl_itsms_bmt]
        where change_owner_id=#{id}
    </select>

    <resultMap id="itsmResultMap" type="com.xxx.model.Itsm">
        <result property="changeNumber" column="change_number"/>
        <result property="itsmUrl" column="itsm_url"/>
        <result property="changeTitle" column="change_title"/>
        <result property="category" column="category"/>
        <result property="status" column="status"/>
        <result property="createdDate" column="created_date"/>
    </resultMap>

</mapper>
```

Dependencies (most are imported using the starters, showing all spelled out since I had trouble getting `mvn dependency:tree` to properly display)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The beginning of the section you linked to reads:

> For each **operation in `CrudRepository`**, Spring Data JDBC runs multiple statements. If there is a `SqlSessionFactory` in the application context, Spring Data checks, for each step, whether the SessionFactory offers a statement. If one is found, that statement (including its configured mapping to an entity) is used.

This works only for the methods in the `CrudRepository`.
Additional methods don't work like this.

You could implement a full blown custom method implementation calling out to MyBatis.

Alternatively you could create an issue and maybe even a PR for named queries backed by MyBatis.

Comment: I had read what you've noted but wasn't sure if I interpreted the statement correctly - thanks for the clarification.  For now I've opened an enhancement request.  https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-362

Comment: Thanks. If you have an idea how to improve the documentation to make this clearer I'd appreciate that as well.